# There is no option for changing the repository in Android SDK Manager

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2022

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK1f9.png)

I am currently coding in Visual Studio 2022 Community Preview. I googled my problem and there I found that changing the repository to Google would solve the problem, but in my android SDK manager, there is no option for changing the repository.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can recheck if you can connect the internet and try again.

Comment: I have a full internet connection. I tried again but the problem is not resolved.

Comment: You can also recheck if you have set up the Android SDK for Xamarin.Android correctly. For more details, check document [Windows Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/windows) and [Setting up the Android SDK for Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows).

Comment: Thanks Jessie Zhang, but that pages are about installing, which I have already done. There is no article on how to change the repository.

Comment: In addition, make sure you have checked the `Auto Install Android SDKs` option when setting android sdk. I have posted an answer, you can check it.

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio includes an Android SDK Manager that you use to download Android SDK tools, platforms, and other components that you need for developing Xamarin.Android apps.

See `Tools` -> `Android` -> `Android SDK Manager`.

Under Platforms you'll find various Android versions for the emulator and under Tools you can install various tools.

**Also**

See `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Xamarin` -> `Android Settings`

and make sure that the `Auto Install Android SDKs` is checked.

There is a folder path called `Android SDK Location`, if it's empty you can browse for it in your computer yourself to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what kind of a problem you were dealing with since I had the same issue.
any ways what I did was delete all installed SDKs and every single detail. so a complete clean snapshot of the installed features and then re-install only essentials.
I would guess the so-called "network problem" in fact has nothing to do with the network but with the storage, since android SDKs are huge in volume you may encounter a wrong message indicating the network problem while the underlying issue is around storage.
[image]
Id the google repository is missing it is because you actually need to install it first
I hope that helps